# Problem in exporting data array to xlsx file using PhpSpreadsheet, how to solve this problem

Tags: phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

when I use phpspreadsheet to export data to excel, wrong code shows like below.[image]

and here is my codes.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');

    $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadSheet, 'Xlsx');
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: I used "ob_end_clean()" or other sth, it still not work T,T